# Passing a dynamically created variable to another function (Vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

I have updated my question to include the code. The "updateNewP" function is not updating the innerHTML but it is not throwing an error. Do I need to add "this" somewhere in both of these functions?
Javascript:

```
let initial = document.getElementById("test");
initial.addEventListener("click", newPElement);

let update = document.getElementById("update");
update.addEventListener("click", updateNewP);

let myTextArea = document.getElementById("textArea");

//function that creates a P
function newPElement(){
let newP = document.createElement("p");
newP.classList.add("myFont");
newP.innerHTML = "Initial Text";
myTextArea.appendChild(newP);
return newP;
}

function updateNewP(newP){
    newP.innerHTML ="Updated";
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Testing</h1>
    <button id="test" class="test">Test</button>
    <button id="update">Update</button>
    <section id="textArea">
    </section>
```

Comment: By "dynamically created variable" do you mean a local variable?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error message. It's just not updating the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `newP` variable that was declared within `functionA` is only available in `functionA`. If you need to work with this variable in a `newPUpdate`, it needs to be passed as an argument:

```js
function functionA() {
  const newP = document.createElement("div");
  newPUpdate(newP);
}

function newPUpdate(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = `${someVariable}`;
}
```

Looking up *variable scope in javascript* will help you understand what's going on.

Comment: thanks but calling the update in the create function automatically updates it. I've edited my initial post and added the code. I think I'm just missing the binding aspect now.

Answer (score 0):

The `addEventListener` passes event to the function. Event does not have the `innerHTML` key because it is not an element.

Comment: Thanks. However, that was recreating a new element because it was calling the function again. I've updated my question and the code. I think I'm just missing the binding piece now.

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying you can't use an event listener to update an element if the element was created dynamically?

Comment: You can, but in your case, `newP` is an event object. That's not an element. So you can store the newly created `p` element in a global variable and then update its `innerHTML` when an event occurs.